# Get Facebook to display my friends from a particular city

Tags: facebook, search

How do I get Facebook to show me just my friends from a particular city?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to your profile
- In your Friends box on the left, click See All
- In the dialog box that pops up click Browse at the top
- Select Show: By City
- Select the desired City

Comment: Nice!  Didn't know about that.

Comment: Lol, bit simpler than my answer! Nice :)

Comment: @x3ja: It wouldn't have surprised me if there wasn't a better way than your answer.  Facebook and usability, eh.

Comment: This no longer works as of October 2019

Answer (score 0):

An October 2019 way of doing this is to type the following in the search bar:

```
My friends who live in Poland
```

Providing the following desired output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit convoluted, but try this:

- Log in to Facebook and click the friends button near the top left - right next to the logo.
- Click on Find Your Friends
- Scroll to the bottom and type the place you're searching for in the box that says "Enter a name or email" and click on the search button
- This will bring up a list of anyone with that in their profile (name, location, network etc) - your friends will be at the top
- Then you can refine the search by location to get people that have that as their registered location by typing the place in the Location box and clicking Refine.

Comment: This no longer works as of October 2019